# Django rest framework url with suffix

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have with url:

```
api/v1/quote/ # list
api/v1/quote/1/ # detail
```

how can i make new url like this:

```
api/v1/quote/1/action
```

and to send post request on this url with parametre `active` true, so it will use `id` from url and `active` from post and then do that action?

Any example for this?

I have this urls code:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'quote', QuoteViewSet)
```

and view:

```
class QuoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Quote.active.all()
    serializer_class = QuoteSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('created_at',)

    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a `Viewset` you can add extra action using the `@detail_route` and `@list_route` decorators ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing))

In your case it could look like this:

```
class QuoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Quote.active.all()
    serializer_class = QuoteSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('created_at',)

    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def action(self, id):
       # put your code here
```

The new `action` method is created automatically be the `DefaultRouter` router and can be accesed through:

```
api/v1/quote/{id}/action
```